# Positioning an element in css on a page at specified pixels

Tags: css, css-float

```
#container
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:5px solid red;
    margin:0px;
}
#hbox1
{
    position:absolute
    left:5px;
    top:5px;
    height:130px;
    width:150px;
    border:5px solid red;
    margin:5px;
}
#hbox2
{
    position:absolute
    left:150px;
    top:5px;
    height:130px;
    width:150px;
    border:5px solid red;
    margin:5px;
}
```

**I need to add hbox2 next right to hbox1 but it is being displayed at bottom of the hbox1... I tried to position hbox2 using absolute positioning...but it doesnt work...**

Comment: Remove that absolute position. and set display inline-block for #hbox1, #hbox2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing semicolons after each `position: absolute`.

Unless you need to use position: absolute for a particular reason, you'd be better off using `float: left` or `display: inline-block` on each box, keeping the elements inside the normal document flow.

Answer (score 2):

using inline-block is also what I would suggest. But don't forget to set font-size:0 on the container div to get rid of any weird spaces.

Also, since you will use inline-block you don't need to set TOP and LEFT anymore making hbox1 and hbox2 identical, in which case you should use a single class instead of two id's

Check it out! I suggest playing around with the values in the link below (hit RUN when you make a change to see the difference) to learn more about what everything does.

http://jsfiddle.net/d7c5g/4/

```
#container{
height:100%;
width:100%;
border:5px solid red;
margin:0px;
font-size:0px;
}
.hbox{
 display:inline-block;
 height:130px;
 width:150px;
 border:5px solid red;
 margin:5px;
}


<div id="container">
    <div class="hbox"></div>
    <div class="hbox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use floats:)

## hbox1

```
{
 float:left
 left:5px;
 top:5px;
 height:130px;
 width:150px;
 border:5px solid red;
 margin:5px;
}
#hbox2
{
 float:left;
 left:150px;
 top:5px;
 height:130px;
 width:150px;
 border:5px solid red;
 margin:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using
    display:inline-block;

Will help keep a more consistent and clean look to your site and code. Floats can actually make your job more difficult if you are working with responsive designing.